# Sort array of strings having dot separated numbers

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have this 2 arrays of strings with dot separated numbers

```
Input1 = [ 'Companies.2', 'Desks.1.1', 'Chairs.1' ]
Input2 = [ 'Assets.2', 'Employees.1' ]
```

on input2 I have tried to remove the(.) and sort but it didn't work

```
var arr = ['Assets.2', 'Employees.1']
var dots = /\./;
var test = []
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].match(dots)) {
        test.push(arr[i].replace(dots, ""))
    }
}
console.log(test.sort());
```

I have tried using .sort() but it only works on strings.

My desired
output1 is `['Chairs.1', 'Companies.2', 'Desks.1.1']`
and output2 is `['Employees.1', 'Assets.2']`

Comment: Please show the code that you tried

Comment: But these *are* strings, no? Also it's not quite clear what the sorting criteria is, or whether you want the same sort on both input array. Even with dots removed, `Assets2` comes before `Employees1`?

Comment: @Bergi yes If i removed the dots Assets2 comes first which is not what I want

Comment: Then what *do* you want? How should your sort work? On that one example input you've given, `input2.reverse()` would do the job to get the expected output, but I doubt that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @MohamedKhalifa Welcome to SO! The problem is, it's not obvious _why_ you want `Employees.1` to come before `Assets.2`. I could guess that it's because the `".1"<".2"` takes precedence over `"A"<"E"`  but then `output` has `Desks.1.1` coming before `Companies.2` which seems to contradict that. Please explain the logic here that is giving you the outputs you show. Thanks.

Comment: @Bergi I want to sort according to the number that comes after the string. input2.reverse() won't work on large array

Comment: @ggorlen My logic here this represents part of a tree structure where [Assets.2, Employees.1] belongs to a parent in the tree structure

Comment: OK, that sounds pretty complex. Could you tell us more about that so we can help you in a way that is meaningful to your application logic? Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen So my tree structure as follow Companies. is the parent [Assets.2, Employees.1] are children of Companies. those children can be parents and have children like Employees.1 can have Assets.1.1

Comment: @MohamedKhalifa Then build a proper tree structure, don't use a `sort` call

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Weird but here you go. I apologize to the community for the name of the sorting function but I had neither the inspiration nor the desire to find better.

EDIT : I just realized that this snippet works for the exemple but doesn't take every case into account, it shouldn't be the accepted answer. OP needs to build a proper tree structure instead of relying to sort() like said @bergi

```js
Input1 = [ 'Companies.2', 'Desks.1.1', 'Chairs.1' ]
Input2 = [ 'Assets.2', 'Employees.1' ]

const sortByNumber = ( a , b ) => {
  return Math.sign(a.split(/\.(.+)/)[1].replace(/\./g, "") - b.split(/\.(.+)/)[1].replace(/\./g, ""))
}

output1 = Input1.sort(sortByNumber)
output2 = Input2.sort(sortByNumber)
console.log(output1)
console.log(output2)
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but if i want the output1 to be `["chairs.1", "Desks.1.1", "Companies.2"]`